# when one option selected in one drop down list then how to display its related value in another drop down list using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```js
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Registration.aspx.cs" Inherits="Practical_5.View.Registration" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <title>Bootstrap</title>
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //function Change() {

        //    if ((document.getElementById('India').checked)) {
        //        document.getElementById('div1').style.visibility = "visible";
        //    }
        //    else {
        //        document.getElementById('di1v').style.visibility = "hidden";
        //    }
        //}

        function toggleDiv() {

            // first check if display then hide otherwise show
            if ((document.getElementById('div1').style.display == 'none')) {
                document.getElementById('div1').style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById('div2').style.display = "none";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('div1').style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById('div2').style.display = "block";
            }
        }
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="background-color: red; font-size: x-large; font-weight: bold; text-align: center"><span>You are registering for Matrimony Meet "Matrimonial Get Together - Pune - 22-Aug-2015"</span></div>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="panel">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <img src="../Images/BJS_Logo-hindi.png" alt="logo" style="height: 71px; width: 161px" />
                        <label class="pull-right" style="font-size: x-large; vertical-align:bottom;margin-top:15px;">Register</label>
                    </div>


                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="mname">Middle Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mname" placeholder="Middle Name" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="sell">Gender</label>
                                    <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                                        <option>Select</option>
                                        <option>Male</option>
                                        <option>Female</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="mnunber">Mobile Number</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mnumber" placeholder="Mobile Number" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-1">
                                <label>India</label>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-1">
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                            <label>
                                                <input value="" type="checkbox" onchange="toggleDiv()"  id="India" />India</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <label>Address</label>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <div id="div1" style="display:none;" class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="state">State</label>
                                            <select class="form-control" id="State">
                                                <option class="active">Select State</option>
                                                <option>Maharashtra</option>
                                                <option>Andhra Pradesh</option>
                                                <option>Gujrat</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
if i select state as maharashtra then i want to display all the cities of maharashtra in following dropdown list.
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="city">City</label>
                                            <select class="form-control" id="city">
                                                <option class="active">Select City</option>
                                                </select>
i want to display automatcally the city dropdown list as
Pune
nagpur
mumbai
nashik
......
......
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
in above code there are div having id div1. in that div there are two dropdown list one for state and one for city. suppose i select one option in state dropdown list eg. i select state maharashtra then i want display all the cities of maharashtra in another dropdown list which is city. how i should
                                 <div id="div2" style="display:block;" class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="state">State</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Text2" placeholder="Enter State" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="city">City</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Text3" placeholder="Enter City" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="zip">Country</label>
                                            <select class="form-control" id="Select1">
                                                <option class="active">Select Country</option>
                                                <option>India</option>
                                                <option>US</option>
                                                <option>Singapore</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="zip">Zip</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zip" placeholder="Enter Zip" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                       

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="lid">Login ID</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lid" placeholder="Login ID" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="pwd">Password</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Password" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="cpwd">Conform Password</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cpwd" placeholder="Conform Password" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-5"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Register Me!</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

please help me how should i do this???
```

Comment: Try creating a listbox for each state but don't display them. Then, like your `div` you display the listbox that corresponds to the State

Comment: I think this is one of the easiest solution without using php

Answer (score 1):

Please see the following working example

```
function populateStates(countryElementId, stateElementId) {

    var selectedCountryIndex = document.getElementById(countryElementId).selectedIndex;

    var stateElement = document.getElementById(stateElementId);

    stateElement.length = 0; // Fixed by Julian Woods
    stateElement.options[0] = new Option('Select State', '');
    stateElement.selectedIndex = 0;

    var state_arr = s_a[selectedCountryIndex].split("|");

    for (var i = 0; i < state_arr.length; i++) {
        stateElement.options[stateElement.length] = new Option(state_arr[i], state_arr[i]);
    }
}

function populateCountries(countryElementId, stateElementId) {
    // given the id of the <select> tag as function argument, it inserts <option> tags
    var countryElement = document.getElementById(countryElementId);
    countryElement.length = 0;
    countryElement.options[0] = new Option('Select Country', '-1');
    countryElement.selectedIndex = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < country_arr.length; i++) {
        countryElement.options[countryElement.length] = new Option(country_arr[i], country_arr[i]);
    }

    // Assigned all countries. Now assign event listener for the states.

    if (stateElementId) {
        countryElement.onchange = function () {
            populateStates(countryElementId, stateElementId);
        };
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mq313sga/